# drupal and wordpress together on one server

Tags: apache

I have two domains:

example1.com - is a drupal site.

example2.com - is a wordpress multisite.

Both domains live on the same physical host. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and Virtualhosts.

Everytime I enable example1.com when I navigate to example2.com (or any domain in my multisite) I get the drupal install page. I should be seeing example 2's index page. Can anyone help? Here are the vhost.conf files

example1 vhost.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example1.com
ServerAlias *.example1.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/example1
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

example2.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example2.com
ServerAlias *.example2.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/example2.com
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

When I disable example1.conf everything with the wordpress multisite (example2.conf) works as expected...

When I try to specify a domain name on the virtualhost (like 
    
 I get an 500 error.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there was a two part problem here. I hadn't properly closed a tag
in my .htaccess file for site example2.

When I removed this, I would get the drupal install page for example1 and example2. What I wound up doing to resolve this issue was to move both virtualhosts into one .conf file in Ubuntu.... for whatever reason that seemed to resolve the issue.